# What is a verb for "illusion"?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, verbs, nouns, dictionaries

What is a verb for *illusion*? I want to use it in a sentence like the following:

> The optical effect [illudes] my perception of its real shape.

<strike>But **illude** does not exist.</strike> But I cannot find *illude* in my Dictionary (OS X Dictionary.app). I want to find a verb that is somewhere between *deceive* and *confuse*.

Comment: I think you might be better off if you rephrased your sentence. "The optical illusion affects my perception of its real shape."

Comment: *Distorts* would also fit. In fact, there ***is*** a verb "to illude" (it's actually the *origin* of the later "illusion"). OED definition 2 says *To trick, impose upon, deceive with false hopes.* So if OP doesn't mind being a bit "obscure/dated", he could just publish and be damned!

Comment: -1 for unwittingly illuding many into believing "illude does not exist".

Comment: Illudes, distorts, befuddles, cons, muddles, fouls, addles, vitiates...

Comment: @Kris, fine. See edit.

Comment: There is a theory which states that if ever anyone discovers exactly what the Universe is for and why it is here, it will instantly disappear and be replaced by something even more bizarre and inexplicable. There is another theory which states that **this has already happened**.

Comment: @Kris hence the strike and more specifics as of where it did not exist. What had disappear? be replaced? and what is there to be bizarre and inexplicable about what had happened? If I violate SE rules, state so and sorry, I'll amend if I miss any.

Comment: Chew on this to know how we continue to illude ourselves on the issue: "***illude*** : (1) To trick, to deceive; (2) to mock, to ridicule. The noun from the verb seems to have left home and moved so far away from its family that it is seldom associated with its origin. **That noun is *illusion*** , "a misleading image or impression." ... ->

Comment: -> ... "The sense of deception remains in the noun but the original sense of the verb (2) has long since fled. This lost connection is to some extent the result of confusion with similar words: allude "refer indirectly", elude "escape, get away from" and delude "deceive by false impression." Don't confuse the four; **only the last is a near synonym.**: ... ->

Comment: -> ... "Here is a nice word that we can save from the brink of extinction by using it as a substitute for other verbs of deception: *Jeannine became a close friend of Jose in order to illude him of her ambition to replace him in his job.* -  Teachers, remind your students not to illude themselves into thinking they can take the weekend off and still do well on your Monday morning quiz. From Lt. *illudere* 'to mock, ridicule' based on in 'in' + *ludere* 'play' based on the noun *ludus* 'game, play,' which may have come from ancient Etruscan. ... ->

Comment: -> ... "The confusion among the words mentioned in today's usage is to some extent the result of 'assimilation.' When the initial consonant of a stem does not like the final consonant of a prefix attached to it, the consonant on the stem converts the prefix consonant into itself (or a consonant it likes), e.g. ex+lude > elude, ad+lude > allude, and in+lude > illude. Why consonants don't get along is anyone's guess; they do much better with vowels." [See: http://thesaurus.babylon.com/illude]

Comment: Does this question allude to the illusion that *illude* is an elision?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think *[confounds](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/confound?s=t)* is often used in this context.

> The optical effect **confounds** my perception of its real shape.

It has a nice feel of causing consternation without deceitfulness or the sort of blundery feel you get from "confuse."  And whereas people tend to be confused, senses are confounded in [literature](http://www.google.com/search?q=confound+the+senses&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1).

Answer (score 46):

Um, what do you mean “*illude* does not exist”?  Sure it does.  It’s just a tad rare these days.  From the OED:

> **illude** /ɪˈl(j)uːd/, *v.* Now *rare*.
>
> Also 6 **illud**.
>
> Etymology: ad. L. *illūdĕre* to make sport of, jest or mock at, ridicule, occas. to trick, impose upon, f. *il-* (**il-**<sup>1</sup>) + *lūdĕre* to play. Cf. obs. Fr. *illuder* (Godef.).
>
> **† 1.** *trans.* To mock, make sport of, deride. *Obs*.
>   **2.** To trick, impose upon, deceive with false hopes.

There a bit more than that, but those other senses are not used any longer; only #2 is.  Here are some citations to go with it:

> - 1670 G. H. *Hist. Cardinals* ɪɪɪ. ɪɪɪ. 293 ― Full of hypocrisie and dissimulation, to lull and illude one another.
> - 1872 M. Collins *Two Plunges for Pearl* I. iii. 64 ― They had allowed their imaginations to illude them.

They also mention the forms *illuded* and *illuding*; for example:

> - 1745 Warton *Pleas. Melanch.* 185 ― The woodman’s stroke, or distant tinkling team··alarms The illuded sense.
> - 1887 *Athenæum* 3 Dec. 745/1 ― They [women] come across unfavourable specimens of the illuding sex.

I’m not saying that you’re apt to skate on entirely thick ice if you were to use these, but *illude* certainly <sub><sup>**DOES**</sup></sub> “exist”, and means pretty much what you would think it means.

Comment: No mention of it being rare [here](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/illude). "He had allowed his imagination to illude him".

Comment: @coleopterist Indeed not; rather, it is marked *literary*, which probably suits it well.

Comment: I think illude is rare enough that readers will think it is a typo of *elude* though, which would sound odd in this context.

Answer (score 10):

I might use the word *obscures* in that sentence:

> The optical effect obscures my perception of its real shape.

From [Oxford Dictionaries](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/obscure): "obscure (verb): Keep from being seen; conceal".

Comment: I like "obscures". It brings in the notion of shadows, which seems appropriate.

Answer (score 8):

What about [deludes](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/delude)? I haven't seen it used as your sentence would have it, but its definition puts it close to your meaning.

Comment: but delude sort of has a feel of fooling someone with intention

Comment: understood -- I sensed that because you wanted something with a hint of "deceive" it would be more appropriate than a word which simply means "confuse"

Comment: You can't delude perception. You can only delude people.

Comment: is there a grammatical rule that dictates that?

Answer (score 6):

> The optical effect **dazzles** my perception of its real shape.

[dazzle:](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dazzle) to lose clear vision especially from looking at bright light

Answer (score 5):

Interesting question.

How about **"deceive"** or **"mislead"**? But I am not sure if you can replace "illudes" with either of these in the sentence you have given.

Answer (score 4):

**mes·mer·ize**  (mzm-rz, ms-)

tr.v. mes·mer·ized, mes·mer·iz·ing, mes·mer·iz·es

> 1. To spellbind; enthrall: "He could mesmerize an audience by the sheer force of his presence" (Justin Kaplan).
> 2. To hypnotize.

Comment: I don't think this word would apply to the O.P.'s context. To *mesmerize* means to *entrance*, and the O.P. is looking for a word that indicates something is *visually* not as it seems. Mesmerize seems much more mental than visual, and I'd say it connotes rapt attention more than illusion. It's still a cool word, though.

Comment: "mzm-rz" seriously, with no vowels?

Comment: “Mesmerize” comes from Franz Mesmer, the German physician who is often credited with having invented hypnosis.  Since visual stimulation (vatch de vatch) is often used to initiate an hypnotic state, and since an optical illusion is another exploitation of the vulnerabilities of the mind, “mesmerize” could work. Its weakness, as you point out, is that, despite its origins, it really does mean transfixing more than misleading.

Answer (score 3):

Obfuscate can work.

1. to confuse, bewilder, or stupefy.
2. to make obscure or unclear: to obfuscate a problem with extraneous information.
3. to darken.

Answer (score 2):

*Deceives* could be appropriate, as in:

> The optical effect deceives my perception of its real shape.

Answer (score 2):

In this context, you might be able to use *distorts*:

> The optical effect **distorts** my perception of its real shape.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps too extreme, but *perverts* might work. Or better maybe, *subverts*.

Comment: Thx @Reg wilco. So it's "quotes," just in titles, and *emph* elsewhere?

Comment: we try to consistently use italics for use–mention distinction. Quotes are used for longer phrases or entire sentences. However, in titles italics simply don't work, so we have to resort to quotes even if it's a single word. Also, within a blockquote it's okay to use bold to highlight a particular word. Do stay away from ***bold italics*** and `code formatting`.

Answer (score 0):

The tricks **baffle**, the performance **astonishes**, **amazes** and **astounds**. It's **magical** and **mystifying** but it includes **misdirection**.

Answer (score -1):

You could use *illusory*, which is an adverb.

Comment: That's actually an adjective.